# Does it serve any purpose to have a CRL with the next update scheduled for 25 years in the future?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

What purpose does it serve to have a CRL with nextUpdate set to +25 years?

A CRL issued by the root of an operating Certificate Authority

```
Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 2 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: ..........
        Last Update: Jun 19 21:19:12 2019 GMT
        Next Update: Jun 12 21:19:12 2044 GMT
        CRL extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: ..........

            X509v3 CRL Number: 
                5
No Revoked Certificates.
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

Well, the CA is for public on-line use. It has the following structure:

```
ROOT
+--INTERMEDIATE  -- a CRL signed by ROOT
   +--END_ENTITY_AUTHORITY  -- a CRL signed by INTERMEDIATE
      +--END_ENTITIES  -- a CRL signed by END_ENTITY_AUTHORITY
```

Only the CRL for END_ENTITIEs is being refreshed, the other two are similarly set to refresh in far future just before the signing certificate expires.

Mike Ounsworth:
From what you say, after reading some of the requirements to get accredited in the operating context, looks like a regulatory requirement fulfillment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be that an IT person said *"I don't want to deal with this"*, and did the CA equivalent of *"Postpone reboot for 100 years"*.

**Or** it could be a CRL intended for an offline environment where the clients validating certs will not have access to the internet to fetch a new CRL. For example, IoT devices inside a car that are communicating with each other over TLS.

It's also not uncommon that the root CA in a hierarchy will be "offline", ie it issues certificates to the intermediate CAs, and then gets shut down. The issuing CAs create CRLs regularly to revoke end-entity certificates, but since a compromised issuing CA would create much larger problems, so it's not worth the effort of waking the root up regularly to publish a CRL.

Either way, it means that this CA doesn't really have the ability to revoke the certificates it issued because clients won't try to fetch a new CRL until `Jun 12 21:19:12 2044 GMT`.